# Postulate of Quantum Mechanics on Wavefunction collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

There is a postulate in quantum mechanics about [wavefunction collapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse). Can anyone provide me some intuitive perspective into it along with the concept of projection (I mean mathematical treatment).

Comment: *"There is a postulate in quantum mechanics about wavefunction collapse"* - I don't see it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics). Not every interpretation recognizes a need for collapse, and thus collapse is not necessarily part of the axiomatic formulation of QM. Could you write down the postulate you are talking about?

Comment: It's not specifically about wavefunction collapse, but it discusses the concept of wavefunction collapse

Comment: I think the OP refers to the so-called von Neumann- Luders  collapse postulate.

Comment: @V.Moretti Yes !!!

Comment: There are lots of sources about that idea in the Internet, look around!

Comment: here there is a quite general review on various collapse approaches http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-collapse/

Comment: [Here's](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4398) a neat article showing the precise difference between von Neumann and Lüders, as well as discussing them quite nicely, imo.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for intuition about the subject, read Dirac's [Principles of Quantum Mechanics](http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/447/Principles%20of%20Quantum%20Mechanics%20-%20Dirac.pdf). You need to read §2, §3 and the beginning of §10 until you see fit.